# How do I delete nodes in igraph in R?

Tags: r, networking, nodes, igraph

I'm trying to write a script that deletes nodes in a Barabasi-Albert Network in R using igraph based on the node's number of connections (I'm trying to recreate some basic results from the "Error and attack tolerance of complex networks" paper by Albert, Jeong and Barabasi). I'm starting by trying to delete five random nodes that have less than the average number of connections of a node in the network. However, when I visualize the network after I attempt to delete the nodes, it does look different, but it doesn't look like the nodes are removed. So I'm not convinced the script is working.

```
nnodes=50 #number of nodes
test.graph<-barabasi.game(nnodes,.5) #create B-A network
test.graph2=test.graph #create a second B-A network for removing nodes
bar_mat=matrix(0,nrow=nnodes,ncol=1) #create empty matrix
for (i in 1:nnodes){
bar_mat[i,]=sum(test.graph[,i]) #sums up the number of connections of each node
}
###Visualizing the network before removing nodes
barabasi.community<-walktrap.community(test.graph) #this is supposed to visualize the most
#connected nodes in the network
members<-membership(barabasi.community)
plot.igraph(test.graph,
        layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,
        vertex.size=10,
        vertex.label.cex=.5,
        edge.arrow.size=.5,
        mark.groups=list(members),
        mark.col="green"
)
f=c()

for (k in 1:5){ #checking five random nodes
 a=sample(1:nrow(bar_mat),1) #select random node
 if(bar_mat[a,]<=mean(bar_mat)){
  test.graph2 <- delete.vertices(test.graph2,a) # this is supposed to delete 
  #the node based on if it has lower than the average amount of connections
  i=i+1 #counting how many nodes of the five are actually removed
 }
f[k]=a #putting the nodes tested into a vector
a=0 #resetting a
}
###Visualizing network after node removal 
barabasi.community2<-walktrap.community(test.graph2)
members2<-membership(barabasi.community2)
plot.igraph(test.graph2,
        layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,
        vertex.size=10,
        vertex.label.cex=.5,
        edge.arrow.size=.5,
        mark.groups=list(members2),
        mark.col="pink"
)
```

The script runs when the number of nodes is smaller (like around 50) but when the number of nodes is higher (around 100) I get the following error:

```
Error in delete.vertices(test.graph2, a) : 
At iterators.c:759 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

I think it has to do with the naming conventions of the nodes, but I'm not sure. I'm new to network science and I'm not the best programmer out there so I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because, since you are sampling randomly from `nrow(bar_mat)` newly each time, you can select a node that has already been deleted. So for example, the loop runs the first time and selects row 24. It will work and delete node 24. It runs again and selects row 12. It will work and delete node 12. It runs again and selects row 24. Now it can't run because the graph does not have node 24 anymore! Otherwise, your code is fine and is indeed deleting nodes.

You can solve this a number of ways, for example by sampling the 5 random nodes all at once (here I do 20 to clearly show that nodes have been deleted):

```r
library(igraph)

nnodes=100 #number of nodes
test.graph<-barabasi.game(nnodes,.5) #create B-A network
test.graph2=test.graph #create a second B-A network for removing nodes
bar_mat=matrix(0,nrow=nnodes,ncol=1) #create empty matrix
for (i in 1:nnodes){
  bar_mat[i,]=sum(test.graph[,i]) #sums up the number of connections of each node
}

vcount(test.graph)
#> [1] 100

# Sample 5 random nodes
set.seed(1491)
a=sample(1:nrow(bar_mat), 20)

for (i in a) {
  if(bar_mat[i,]<=mean(bar_mat)){a
    test.graph2 <- delete.vertices(test.graph2,i)
    }
  }
#> Error in delete.vertices(test.graph2, i): At iterators.c:759 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id

vcount(test.graph)
#> [1] 100
vcount(test.graph2)
#> [1] 88
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>